# Is there a way to add an input field with a default value that a user can rename dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm looking for the capability to allow a user to change text on a page dynamically, but I haven't found anything relating to what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know of a way to add this functionality? Is there a library or can I use Vue (which is part of our project) to do this?

[The final result I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV5VJ.png)

The idea is to allow a user to rename 'Project 1' by pressing the icon on the right, to a name of their choosing, and then save it so the new name is seen every time that user visits the page.

Any help or insight as to how I can get this or build this functionality would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is it different from changing the value of any other input field?

Comment: AngularJS is godly for these things.

Comment: Can you provide some code that you've tried? In Vue or Vanilla JS this is very simple, but understandably we're here to help not to write things for you.

Comment: The answers you've received so far all assume you want to change the title of the document the user is visiting (for the period of time the user is visiting that specific document). I don't believe this is actually what you want to do, but can't really tell. Please [edit] your question to be more clear. See [ask] for tips on what makes a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this two ways. The first only doesn't require any libraries. The second requires [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/).

```html
<title></title>
<input onkeypress="document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = this.value">
```

OR

```html
<title>{{input}}</title>
<input ng-model="input">
```

Comment: OP uses vueJS nor Angular

Comment: He said "is there a library I can use or Vue." That means we are not restricted to just Vue.js

Comment: check this out **or can I use Vue (which is part of our project) to do this?**

Comment: It is not worth bringing in a dependency on Angular (let alone an older library like AngularJS) just to be able to change the title of an HTML page.

Comment: True, that is why I added the way of using pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it with vanilla JS:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('title');
el.onkeyup = function(e) {
   window.document.title = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
New Page Title: <input type="text" id="title">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    Title:
    <input id="userTitle" type="text" name="lname"></input>
    <button onclick="changeTitle()">Change Title</button>
    <script>
        function changeTitle() {
            document.title = document.getElementById('userTitle').value;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
​
```